# What is the correct procedure to store a utf-16 encoded rss stream into sqlite3 using python

Tags: python, sqlite, wsgi

I have a python sgi script that attempts to extract an rss items that is posted to it and store the rss in a sqlite3 db.  I am using flup as the WSGIServer.
To obtain the posted content:
    postData = environ["wsgi.input"].read(int(environ["CONTENT_LENGTH"]))

To attempt to store in the db:

```
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite
ldb = sqlite.connect("/var/vhost/mysite.com/db/rssharvested.db")
lcursor = ldb.cursor()
lcursor.execute("INSERT into rss(data) VALUES(?)", (postData,))
```

This results in only the first few characters of the rss being stored in the record:
ÿþ<
I believe the initial chars are the BOM of the rss.

I have tried every permutation I could think of including first encoding rss as utf-8 and then attempting to store but the results were the same.  I could not decode because some characters could not be represented as unicode.

Running python 2.5.2
sqlite 3.5.7

Thanks in advance for any insight into this problem.

---

Here is a sample of the initial data contained in postData as modified by the repr function, written to a file and viewed with less:

'\xef\xbb\xbf

Thanks for the all the replies!  Very helpful.

---

The sample I submitted didn't make it through the stackoverflow html filters will try again, converting less and greater than to entities (preview indicates this works).

\xef\xbb\xbf<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><rss xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><channel><item d3p1:size="0" xsi:type="tFileItem" xmlns:d3p1="http://htinc.com/opensearch-ex/1.0/">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the SQL insertion you should to convert the string to unicode compatible strings. If you raise an UnicodeError exception, then encode the string.encode("utf-8").

Or , you can autodetect encoding and encode it , on his encode schema.  [Auto detect encoding](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52257)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the insertion encoding - in any decent database API, you should insert `unicode` strings and `unicode` strings only.

For the reading and parsing bit, I'd recommend Mark Pilgrim's [Feed Parser](http://www.feedparser.org/).  It properly handles BOM, and the license allows commercial use.  *This may be a bit too heavy handed if you are not doing any actual parsing on the RSS data.*

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your incoming data are encoded as UTF-16 (otherwise known as UCS-2)?

UTF-16 encoded unicode strings typically include lots of NUL characters (surely for all characters existing in ASCII too), so UTF-16 data hardly can be stored in environment variables (env vars in POSIX are NUL terminated).

Please provide samples of the `postData` variable contents. Output them using `repr()`.

Until then, the solid advice is: in all DB interactions, your strings on the Python side should be unicode strings; the DB interface should take care of all translations/encodings/decodings necessary.

Comment: Note: UCS-2 is critically different from UTF-16 on several points.  ----- Specifically: a) UCS-2 cannot represent every possible Unicode character like UTF-16 can --- b) characters in a UCS-2 are all 2 bytes in length, while characters in a UTF-16 string may be longer (surrogate pairs).